# Level lawn to Laying plastic shed with membrane

Tags: lawn, soil

I have ordered a shed and whole slab pavement/patio seem like a big job I ordered plastic based 8*6 shed base with membrane.  Now I want to lay it, some suggest we can just lay builder’s sand as base, level it and but membrane with shed base on top.
I am based in UK and it’s always rainy as soil is moist? What can be best way to do the job before shed and people arrive to assemble it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you ordered your plastic shed base from, but guidance is given here https://www.plasticshedbase.co.uk/content/6-how-to-build-a-plastic-shed-base- on what to put beneath it. You're still going to need to dig out, compact (probably with a whacker if your soil is not clay). lay heavy duty geotextile membrane,  backfill with aggregate or hard core of some sort, with a layer of sand on top. Check what instructions the company you ordered from gives on this subject.

Comment: Where is what I ordered and got https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00UTRKI24/ref=cm_sw_r_oth_api_i_ol66DbDDRN40F one of video on YouTube I saw said there r 2 options. One is what u mention other is is flat out the builder sand on area u want to put and then membrane and shed base with gravel on side to hold it down

Comment: https://youtu.be/vDRrmHMaQ1s the video link

Comment: If your soil is light (not heavy clay), living where you do in a high rainfall area, you will need to bed it onto something more solid than sand, otherwise the shed may sink or  tip over time. Up to you though

Comment: I have a larger plastic shed that is on a 10-20 cm base of compacted "base gravel" (1 cm pieces of limestone, with "fines"). My soil is well-draining loam, at the bottom of a very slight grade, so it's often wetter than the rest of the yard. Because the homeowner who put in the shed did NOT use sand, and given that the rainfall where I live is NOT as heavy as in the UK, I don't think sand will be correct for you.

Comment: I got 10cm of gravel. so my plan is to remove to turf, make the sub-base level and then put in gravel to make it leveled with walking on it as shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIA4YAKrZds

Comment: Also the shed has a metal base, so gravel, membrane on top, shed base on top of all.